# Dificuldade para decompor series temporais no r

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Estou tentando utilizar o R pela primeira vez. Estou tentando avaliar possíveis choques em um modelo VAR, logo não consigo desenvolver o teste de decomposição. sendo o meu principal questionamento  a mensagem ***"série temporal não tem período, ou tem menos de 2"***

A principio utilizei o seguinte código.

```
    dados.ts <- ts(data = Lmacro$PIB, frequency = 1)
    dados.ts.dec <- decompose(dados.ts, type = "mult")
```

1. Sendo `Lmacro`, os dados logaritmos do meu modelo a principio iniciei pela variável `PIB`.
2. Infelizmente eu não conheço as demais características da função.
3. A planilha possui identificação dos anos, porém eu não saberei dizer como associei aos dados ou se associei.

base de dados em excel XLSX.
https://gitlab.com/fellipesillvaoff/TCC/blob/master/tcc%20excel_pt.xlsx

Características do sistema:

```
    R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

    Matrix products: default

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
    [5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] vars_1.5-2        lmtest_0.9-35     urca_1.3-0                                strucchange_1.5-1 sandwich_2.4-0   
    [6] zoo_1.8-1         MASS_7.3-49       Matrix_1.2-12    

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.4.1  tools_3.4.1     nlme_3.1-131.1  grid_3.4.1              lattice_0.20-35
```

**Obrigado.**

Comment: Eu creio que essa mensagem de erro diz tudo, se a série tem menos de 2 períodos é porque não é periódica e não vale a pena insistir. Não está nos dados. Eu começaria por `acf` e `pacf`. Depois, talvez (de certeza) `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme resposta do Rui.
Para o caso especifico não existe um retorno viável para o comando, pois realmente a resposta séria inferior ou igual a 2 períodos.